# The negation operator in JS

Tags: javascript

Why in this case

```
if (! x === y) {
console.log ('true');
} else {
console.log ('false');
}
```

gets `false` since the negation operator is used. Without the negation operator it also gets `false` because the operator `===`checks if it compares the same values with the same data type. Why, then, after putting the exclamation point directly after x, does he still get `false`, since it contradicts falsehood, so I should get the truth?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please give full code examples. This includes input data and expected behavior

Comment: `if (! x === y)` is negating only `x`, not the whole expression. So `if ((! x) === y)`.

Comment: Did you mean `x !== y`? - `console.log(x !== y)`

Comment: Related: [Should I use !== or ==! when checking for not equal?](/q/22246632/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!x` negates `x`, then compares that to `y`. Assuming `x` is *truthy*, `!x` is `false`. So unless `y` is exactly `false`, `!x === y` is `false`. Read as: *negated x equals y*.

`x === y` is probably also `false` because the two values aren't equal.

`x !== y` is the negated comparison operator, meaning *"is not equal"*. So where `x === y` is `false`, `x !== y` is `true`.

`x !== y` is equivalent to `!(x === y)`, negating the *entire result*, not just `x`.